# Is there a way to read from a text or yaml file and pass its data to <arg> tag?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just like `rosparam` that take yaml file as a parameter, I want to know if there is a way to read text or yaml file that contains parameters and pass the parameters to any attributes of the `<arg>` tag (e.g. `value`, `default`).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274609/is-there-a-way-to-read-from-a-text-or-yaml-file-and-pass-its-data-to-%3Carg%3E-tag?/) by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I'm aware, you can't use launch files to read individual parameters in yaml files and/or change them. You can, however, use an `arg` tag to specify a file path and pass the file name to the launch file. For example, let's call the following launch file `launch1.launch`:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="file_name" default="$(find my_package)/my_yaml.yaml"/>   
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg file_name)"/>
</launch>
```

Then you can `include` this launch file from other launch files and use the `file_name` `arg` to dynamically change what yaml file you're using. For example, let's call the following launch file `launch2.launch`:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="file_name" default="$(find my_package)/another_yaml.yaml"/>

    <include file="$(find my_package)/launch1.launch">
        <arg name="file_name" value="$(arg file_name)"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

This would result in `launch1.launch` being used with the yaml file passed to it (`another_yaml.yaml`) instead of its default of `my_yaml.yaml`.

An alternative approach is to load the yam with out the parameters that you want to change during launch and set those as arguments. Here's `launch3.launch`:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="file_name" default="$(find my_package)/my_yaml.yaml"/>
    <arg name="param1" default="0"/>
    <arg name="param2" default="1"/>

    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg file_name)" />
    <param name="param1" value="$(arg param1)"/>
    <param name="param2" value="$(arg param2)"/>
</launch>
```

A good way to get how this all works is to read other projects' launch files and to just experiment (oh, and read the [launch file wiki entry](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) too).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on 2017-10-30**:
Thanks for your help. I actually need to find some way to make individual parameters be read from the yaml file and pass each as an argument to machine tags in the launch file. I appreciate your help!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-30**:
What's the reason behind doing it that way? The way I'm describing is straightforward and pretty standard.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2021-02-11**:
This really doesn't address the problem the OP is having.